# C# WPF - Cut and then copy an entire Excel row

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I have to edit an Excel sheet with a WPF in C# and already ordered the rows by one column. But now I need to cut a few rows and write them to another position in the sheet.

Is ther anyway to completely cut out an entire row and insert this row to another position in the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been answered

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/78059590-c294-47b4-a656-aec8ca51779f/c-excel-cut-or-copy-an-excel-row-and-move-to-another-row?forum=exceldev

Comment: Please, [Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._